# Adding more than 2 metrics to a Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, timeline

Is it possible to track more than two metrics in a timeline on Google Analytics?

Specifically I would like to track two events and compare it against visits; however, whenever I try to do that with the timeline widget I can only compare visits against one event.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: go to behavior -> events. Select the checkboxes in front of the events that you want to examine. At the head of the data table click "plot rows". This will display values  for the selected events in the graph. Now go to the dropdown box right above the graph and select "visits". This will add the data for visits to the graph.

I attached a sample image so you can see if this is what you are after. Relevant bits are marked red-ish.

[image]